# How to use shell to listen the mouse?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a small shell script to monitor the mouse&keyboard. It will be used to take a picture for every person who login a Linux computer. But I don't know how to realize this only with shell. Is there any solution?

Comment: seem like youre trying to do something the hard way.  what do you really want?

Comment: Think about that: one picture every mouse click or key pressed? Or, even if you want only 1 picture, such program would capture the input of the keyboard/mouse, which then wouldn't work properly until the program exits. Maybe a better approach would be to create a script that takes a picture every time a person logs in (the triggering event would be the log in itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current mouse location you can call:

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

From there, execute this every few seconds and look if the mouse moved.